# Json array to php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to save these data coming from API, coin names, which are "assets", and balances that are "free" to MYSQL. However, it adds an empty row to the database. code as below. How should I do?

API view;

```
Array ( [makerCommission] => 10 [takerCommission] => 10 [buyerCommission] => 0 [sellerCommission] => 0 [canTrade] => 1 [canWithdraw] => 1 [canDeposit] => 1 [updateTime] => 1615737088938 [accountType] => SPOT [balances] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [asset] => BTC [free] => 0.00000001 [locked] => 0.00000000 ) [1] => Array ( [asset] => LTC [free] => 0.00000000 [locked] => 0.00000000 ) [2] => Array ( [asset] => ETH [free] => 0.00000000 [locked] => 0.00000000 ) [3] => Array ( [asset] => NEO [free] => 0.00000000 [locked] => 0.00000000 ) [4] => Array ( [asset] => BNB [free] => 0.00066371 [locked] => 0.00000000 )
```

MY CODE;

```
    $execResult = curl_exec($ch);
    $Balances = json_decode($execResult, true); 
    foreach($Balances as $row);
      
    {
    $query .= "INSERT INTO table (asset, free, locked) VALUES('" . $row["asset"] . "', '" . $row["free"] . "', '" . $row["locked"] . "')";
    if(mysqli_multi_query($coonect, $query))
```

Comment: Please consider why [you shouldn't paste code or sample data as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Use prepared statements to prevent mySQL injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The balances array you are accessing is another level down in `$Balances` so you should be using

```
foreach($Balances['balances'] as $row)
```

and you should be using prepared statements to protect yourself from SQL injection attacks.